# Citations aren't working in included file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, mactex

Citations I place in included files come up as a '`?`', yet citations I place in the main file come up correctly. When the same citation is in both, it appears on both.

I am compiling it in the order of `pdflatex`>`bibtex`>`pdflatex`>`pdflatex`; I think this is the correct order.

I am using Mac OS X lion and MacTeX.

Have I done something wrong?

```
% main.tex
\documentclass [12pt]{report}
\usepackage {natbib, graphicx}

\begin {document}

\include {introduction}
\include {background}

\bibliographystyle {pjgsm}
\bibliography {bibliography}
\addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end {document}
```

Comment: So does `introduction.tex` and `background.tex` include their own `\bibliography{..}` commands?

Comment: No, they don't; I tried that with no success.

Comment: not directly relevant to the question, but do check the page number of the bibliography in the toc; if your bibliography is longer than one page, this page number probably won't be correct.

Comment: @barbara beeton - thanks; I'll make sure to fix that

Comment: This should work, and does for me (using a different `.bst` file, since the `pjgsm.bst` I found online seems to have an error. But that shouldn't make any difference.)  When you compile your file what does the log or the console output show when you run the `bibtex` part of the compilation?

Comment: Have you tried to compile more than once? Sometimes I experience the same error but compiling two or three times normally fixes it.

Comment: @aulste I've tried compiling it multiple times in many different ways and it's made no difference. When I include the files with \input they work

Comment: I think you spotted the problem by yourself: either use `\input` instead of `\include` or try bibtexing each of the included files rather than main...